# Expectation of power function in Gamma Distribution?

Tags: expectation, gamma-distribution

If $X$~Gamma($\alpha,\beta$), does the expectation of power function, $E[X^t], t>0$, have a closed-form solution? I know that when $t$ is a positive integer (natural number), $E[X^t]$ can be calculated by using the moment generating function $M_X(t)$. I have a question when t is positive real number, $t\in R_+$.

Comment: *[Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)* is some MathJax tutorial.

Comment: In other words, you want a closed-form solution for the $t^{th}$ moment of a Gamma rv. See, for instance, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaDistribution.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any moment generating function. Recall that
$$
\Gamma_{\alpha,\beta}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x/\beta}
$$
So you multiply $X^{k}$ on the front just change the kernel to a different set of value, say $(\alpha+k, \beta)$. The rest you can derive yourself by taking the quotient.